Quarkus native image init dto
Dozer mapper can't find the constructor of some dtos in native image quarkus
org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: fr.usu.server.dto.instance.server.ServerPhysicalDto.()
at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.throwMappingException(MappingUtils.java:82)

here example of dto doasn't work with the mapping dozer
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class ServerPhysicalDto extends ServerDto {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Integer coreCount;
Boolean isMultiThreadSmt;
Integer maxSocket;
Long memoryMb;
Integer populatedSocket;
Integer procCount;
String procFrequency;
Integer threadPerCore;


Have you tried the quarkus annotation @RegisterForReflection on the dto?

I tried this annotation but it doesn't work @RegisterForReflection,  when I added this  config {
"name": "fr.usu.server.dto.instance.server. ServerPhysicalDto",
"allDeclaredConstructors": true,
"allDeclaredMethods": true
} on native-image/reflect-config.json file it works , now I search something to make it generic
